# How to verify an email in firebase auth in flutter?

Tags: firebase, email, authentication, flutter, dart

I've created a login screen using firebase & flutter and Everything is going okay but I want the user to sign in with a real email (verified) not any email.

if the user clicks signs in button with an email like that : shsuhsafk@uisl.com, it will accept this email.

how to verify that the email isn't fake and actually belong to a real address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to really verify the users e-mail address you need to send a verification mail which requires action from the user.

Only checking if the address exists is insufficient as the e-mail address could belong to anyone.

You can set up a mail template in your Firebase Console and use the following code to send the verification mail.

```
FirebaseUser user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
     try {
        await user.sendEmailVerification();
        return user.uid;
     } catch (e) {
        print("An error occured while trying to send email        verification");
        print(e.message);
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String email = "user@example.com";
try {
  String link = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().generateSignInWithEmailLink(
      email, actionCodeSettings);
  // Construct email verification template, embed the link and send
  // using custom SMTP server.
  sendCustomPasswordResetEmail(email, displayName, link);
} catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
  System.out.println("Error generating email link: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Please refer Below link for more info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/email-action-links